# Ping with negative time

Tags: ping

Today I've test my connection and after some hours the result is the following

```
 --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
 19482 packets transmitted, 19092 packets received, 2.0% packet loss
 round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = -164.144/75.413/1752.758/100.035 ms
```

How is possible that the minimum time is less than zero?

Comment: Local clock skew? Did you restart NTP or otherwise step the local clock?

Comment: No, I didn't restart nothing explicity. My pc was on table and I went out